Adjust Macro to also copy cell background/fill color
I have this Marco below currently working, I would like to add the function of also copying the cell background color too if possible.
Sub test()
  Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
  Dim f As Range
  Dim j As Long, lr1 As Long, lr As Long

  
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Labor Mapping")
  
  With Sheets("Labor Mapping")
    .Rows(2 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Clear
    End With
  
  For Each sh In Sheets
    If sh.Name <> sh1.Name Then
        lr1 = sh1.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row + 1
      
      lr = sh.Cells.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
      
      For j = 1 To sh.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(1).Column
        Set f = sh1.Rows(1).Find(sh.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
        
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
          sh1.Cells(lr1, f.Column).Resize(lr).Value = sh.Cells(2, j).Resize(lr).Value
    
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
  
  Sheets("Labor Mapping").Columns("G").Delete

End Sub


You can use .Value(11) instead of .Value to copy values with base formatting.
sh1.Cells(lr1, f.Column).Resize(lr).Value(11) = sh.Cells(2, j).Resize(lr).Value(11)


Not sure if this is what you are looking for, I think there might be a shorter way to put it, but I am trying to use the range attribute:
sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(lr1, f.Column),sh1.Cells(lr1, f.Column)).Interior.Color = sh.Range(sh.Cells(2, j),sh.Cells(2, j)).Interior.Color

I might be adding it incorrectly to the Marco cause only the first row is copying the background color correctly

But it is in the direction I want to go
